# Razor looping through Viewbag and bind to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewbag

I have list of objects in my coming from controller.

it looks like this

```
{ Driver = System.Data.Entity.Driver_Driver1, Statuss = NotConfirmed }
{ Driver = System.Data.Entity.Driver_Driver2, Statuss = NotConfirmed }
```

please note that Driver is a complex type object.

Controller:

```
var Drivers = _db.Drivers.Where(x => x.DriverCompanyID == id).Where(d => d.CanWorkIn.Where(f => f.CompanyToDriveFor.CompanyID == OwnCompany.CompanyID).Any())
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Driver = x,
                        Statuss = x.CanWorkIn.FirstOrDefault().Status.ToString()

                    }).ToList();

ViewBag.ListOfDrivers = Drivers;
return PartialView("_DriverList");
```

My Model

```
   public class DriverViewItem 
    {
        public Driver Driver { get; set; }
        public string Statuss { get; set; }
    }
```

My View

```
@model List<MyApp.web.Models.DriverViewItem>
```

and this last bit does not work. **model declaration.**

Comment: Can you show more precisely how you are *adding* the code to the ViewBag?

Comment: You should be using a model to parse complex data to a view

Comment: I have Linq query.

 `.Select(x => new { 
       Driver = x,
       Statuss = x.CanWorkIn.FirstOrDefault().Status
    }).ToList();`

Comment: You should look at strongly typing the anonymous type and parsing the list as a model from the Controller to the view

Comment: @AshleyMedway so what's the problem in sending anonymous object to the view and how do you know that the `OP` is not already using strongly-typed View with another model?

Comment: @Leron then the action should be a partial, you shouldn't be sending complex data view the viewbag

Comment: Ashley, I have tried to pass data through model, but getting the same problem, selecting right object in foreach loop.

Comment: @AshleyMedway `then the action should be a partial` - I guess you mean that the `Action` should call a `PartialView` (as it is from what the edited question show). However, the last time I was using `ASP.NET MVC` the `View` and the `PartialViews` were sharing the same `model` is this changed now?

Comment: @Leron in a view you can call `@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")` to which can return a partial view result with separate model.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the model instead to pass this kind of data.  But to answer the question directly, in the controller, assign it as an array of items to the viewbag

```
ViewBag.Data = {
    new { Driver = System.Data.Entity.Driver_Driver1, Status = NotConfirmed },
    new { Driver = System.Data.Entity.Driver_Driver2, Status = NotConfirmed }
}
```

And in the markup:

```
@{
  if (ViewBag.Data != null){
     foreach (var item in ViewBag.Data) {
        //show the item in the view
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this technically answers the question this is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

First create a strongly typed class with the properties you require. I've called mine `DriverViewItem`.

Then in your controller change the select to select this `DriverViewItem` and parse the list as a model to the view.

```
var Drivers = _db.Drivers.Where(x => x.DriverCompanyID == id).Where(d => d.CanWorkIn.Where(f => f.CompanyToDriveFor.CompanyID == OwnCompany.CompanyID).Any())
            .Select(x => new DriverViewItem()
            {
                Driver = x,
                Statuss = x.CanWorkIn.FirstOrDefault().Status

            }).ToList();

return PartialView("_DriverList", Drivers);
```

In the view you will need to tell the view to expect your model you can do this with:

```
@model List<DriverViewItem>
```

Then you can iterate through the items like so:

```
@foreach(DriverViewItem item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <p>@item.Driver.{what ever property}</p>
        <p>@item.Statuss</p>
    </div>
}
```

This is a much cleaner way than parsing data using the ViewBag.

Comment: I have tried like this, so maybe I am getting the model wrong,
   `public class DriverViewItem 
    {
        public Driver Driver { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @user3812199 That looks correct to me. It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code? Do you have your code in an online source control?

Comment: I have it on visual studio online

Comment: I have changed the code, adding ToString on  `Statuss = x.CanWorkIn.FirstOrDefault().Status.ToString()` and seems cant get a model right, the pipe between controller and view does not work.